# import .log file in elasticsearch and Kibana

Tags: json, elasticsearch, curl, kibana, logfile

I have this .log file with JSON and it looks like this

```
    {"method":"GET","path":"/public/index","format":"html","controller":"public","action":"index","status":200,"duration":84.59,"view":33.7,"db":47.45,"ip":"127.0.0.1","route":"public#index","request_id":"4d7016832294bafa8f593453eed2adb1","source":"unknown","tags":["request"],"@timestamp":"2018-11-09T22:54:06Z","@version":"1"}
{"method":"GET","path":"/public/index","format":"html","controller":"public","action":"index","status":200,"duration":15.44,"view":13.85,"db":0.91,"ip":null,"route":null,"request_id":null,"source":"unknown","tags":["request"],"@timestamp":"2018-11-09T22:54:28Z","@version":"1"}
{"method":"GET","path":"/public/index","format":"html","controller":"public","action":"index","status":200,"duration":13.86,"view":12.47,"db":0.8,"ip":null,"route":null,"request_id":null,"source":"unknown","tags":["request"],"@timestamp":"2018-11-09T22:54:40Z","@version":"1"}
```

and i try to import this in elasticsearch and Kibana.
I tried with this code in command line

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test/test" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @logfile.log
```

and i get this error

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Malformed content, found extra data after parsing: START_OBJECT"}},"status":400}
```

and when i look in Kibana I see this

[image: this is what i have in Kibana]

what i am doing wrong?

Comment: so, after a lot of research i figure out that i have multiple documents in the logfile, and not only one document. I should send only one document or use the bulk API.
how can i change my file to only one document, or how do i change the file content to conform with bulk format ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bulk format is

```
action_and_meta_data\n
optional_source\n
action_and_meta_data\n
optional_source\n
....
```

You have all the `optional_source` lines in your file already.

Just add a line containing 
`{ "index" : { "_index" : "YOUR-INDEX-NAME", "_type" : "_doc"} }` 
before **each** of your lines.

Then POST against the bulk api in ES https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html

Comment: thanks @ibexit,
I really have a hard time here. How can i add this line to the file before each line?
I use the gem logstasher

Comment: hey @mat's. Let´s see if I can help you. What OS are you working on? Are you familiar with Linux shell? If so, try this: `awk -v FS="" '{print "{ \"index\" : { \"_index\" : \"YOUR-INDEX-NAME\", \"_type\" : \"_doc\"} }\n"$0}' bulk_file_name > bulk_preprocessed`

Comment: thanks. i found a way to add a line in the logstasher.rb (in initializer)
and it works perfect.